# Explanation of Transaction Data Structures

Tags: nearprotocol

As of 10/4/22, the [page for the Transaction data structure](https://nomicon.io/DataStructures/Transaction) is blank in the NEAR Protocol specification. Reading the [overview page for transactions in the near docs](https://docs.near.org/concepts/basics/transactions/overview#transaction-status) gives an example response to an RPC API call that shows a transaction with the following structure:

```
"transaction": {
    "actions": [
      { "Transfer": { "deposit": "50000000000000000000000000" } }
    ],
    "hash": "EL9cEcoiF1ThH1HXrdE5LBuJKzSe6dRr7tia61fohPrP",
    "nonce": 51,
    "public_key": "ed25519:5zset1JX4qp4PcR3N9KDSY6ATdgkrbBW5wFBGWC4ZjnU",
    "receiver_id": "transfer-vote.near",
    "signature": "ed25519:37rcwcjDBWWAaaRYCazHY72sfDbmudYvtmEBHMFmhYEfWD3mbrgrtYs5nVh9gzRUESELRDET9g72LnAD2BWdSgKu",
    "signer_id": "near"
  }
```

But in the same response at the top level (not nested within the transaction), there is also a `status`, a `transaction_outcome`, and a `receipts_outcome`. This presentation brings up questions like:

- Are `status`, `transaction_outcome`, and `receipts_outcome` actually nested in `transaction` data structures? Or are `transaction` and `transaction_outcome` separate data structures entirely?
- `receipts_outcome` and `transaction_outcome` appear to have the same structure. Are they actually the the same underlying data structure, but presented with different names?
- `receipts_outcome` and `transaction_outcome` (or whatever the underlying data structure is) each have their own `status` field, and this makes sense. But how can the top level `status` field exist with no information about the transaction it is related to? Is it actually part of a `transaction`?

I understand things are presented this way because it is an rpc response, but what are the underlying data structures for NEAR transactions and outcomes?

Comment: Those finding this question and looking for the answer might be interested in having a look at the structures RPC uses under the hood.
TX: https://github.com/near/nearcore/blob/5b7861187511a912e61603245c60dfc512c5145a/core/primitives/src/views.rs#L1212-L1220

Comment: And Outcomes: https://github.com/near/nearcore/blob/5b7861187511a912e61603245c60dfc512c5145a/core/primitives/src/views.rs#L1487-L1507